# Spring constructor params?

Tags: java, spring

Some of my classes have final fields that are populated from the constructor as well as properties that can be assigned from getters and setters.

If I can do this using spring, what does the springcontext.xml file look like that creates objects in this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<bean id="testWithConstructorArg"
        class="com.Test">
        <constructor-arg ref="referencingSomething"/>
</bean>
```

more: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18396.html

Answer (score 1):

`<bean id="myBean" class ="com.example.MyClass">`
`<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">`
`<value>hello world</value>`
`</constructor-arg>`
`</bean>`

then you can have the normal setter/getter based `<paramater name="blah" value="whatever"/>` as usual.